# change style of specific days in a calendar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, children

I have a calendar in javascript and I want to change the style of specific days.

The structure of the calendar is:

```
    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2015">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a>
    </td>
    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2015">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a>
    </td>
    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2015">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a>
    </td>
   .
   .
   .
```

I want to select the day 13 and the day 15 using Jquery, but I'm using something like this, but it doen't work:

```
var value = $("td[data_month=" + month+ "][data_year=" + year+ "]")
            .first().html();
```

value is undefined, why??????

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong tags. `data_month` and `data_year`

Fixed here:

```
var value = $("td[data-month=" + month + "][data-year=" + year+ "]").children().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use correct data attributes in your selector (see Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jmou7js6/1/)

```
var month = '3';
var year = '2015';
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var value = $("td[data-month=" + month + "][data-year=" + year+ "]")
        .first().html();
   alert(value);
```

});